Is the reverse inequality for Grönwall's inequality also correct?
I seems my question is different from this question. The version of Grönwall's inequality from wikipedia says if $u'(t) \leq \beta(t) u(t)$ then $u(t) \leq u(a) \exp(\int_{a}^t \beta(s) ds)$. Is it also true that if $u'(t) \geq \beta(t) u(t)$ then $u(t) \geq u(a) \exp(\int_{a}^t \beta(s) ds)$? It seems that the proof in Wikipedia hold with just flipping the signs. Am I correct or missing something?

Yes, your "reverse Gronwall inequality" is true in the case $u(t)$ is positive: suppose $u'(t)\geq \beta(t) u(t)$. Then $$\frac{d}{dt}\ln(u(t))=\frac{u'(t)}{u(t)}\geq \beta(t).$$ Then integrating from $a$ to $t$, we get $$\ln(u(t))-\ln(u(a))\geq\int_a^t\beta(s)\,ds,$$
and thus
$$u(t)\geq u(a)\exp\left(\int_a^t\beta(s)\,ds\right).$$
